# What's the point in locking this closed question?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The question [Why did the openai's gym website close?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/4027/4) was closed. Then it was locked. What's the point in locking this question?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the reason.](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts)

> An extremely **popular** question which is now considered **inappropriate** for the site may be locked for "Historical Significance": this alters the appearance of the question, automatically locks all answers as well, and disables flagging completely. This lock should be reserved for cases where a **cherished cultural artifact would otherwise be deleted**

If you want, I can delete the post. However, I thought that, given it's related to RL, it may have some significance for us (but not much, in my view).

Comment: Thanks. Do you plan to lock or delete all off-topic questions?

Comment: Only posts that can still be "useful/interesting" for us (i.e. with respect to our current scope) will be locked and not deleted. Off-topic posts that have little value and that exist because our site was still in a "definition" phase may be deleted (without being locked first). Note that our site was in public beta for many years and **many** off-topic (and poor) questions were asked. So, there was the need to clean up a lot of these off-topic posts.